# efficient creation of json from mysql output - grouping within uniques

Tags: php, mysql, json, performance

I believe I have been writing some inefficient code here, but can't seem to figure out a more efficient way of writting it.

This often happens with json output, though I've had the issue with some html or xml output as well.

I run a query in my database which brings back an array. Say a persons favorite foods. 
php's mysql_fetch_assoc returns

```
 
Array([person]=>john [food]=>chocolate)
Array([person]=>john [food]=>pizza)
Array([person]=>john [food]=>coffee)
Array([person]=>susan [food]=>licorice)
```

To create my json or html, i've been looping through looking for unique persons, and then adding the food like this

```
$jsonOut=''
$personAdd='';
while($gotArray=mysql_fetch_assoc(foodArray)){

if($personAdd!='$gotArray['person']){
$jsonOut.="person: $gotArray['person'], foods{";
}
$jsonOut.="food:$gotArray['food'],";
rtrim(jsonOut,',');
$jsonOut.="}";
$personAdd=$array['person'];
}
```

Now, this isn't a big deal when you only have one value that is repeated constantly in the mysql response, but when you start having 4 or 5 columns where the values are the same, it starts to get quite verbose.

Is there a better way to do this?

-------------Clarifying what the output should look like -----------------
The final json for the above arrays should look like this

```
[
    {
        "person": "john",
        "foods": [
            {
                "food": "chocolate",
                "food": "pizza",
                "food": "coffee" 
            } 
        ] 
    },
    {
        "person": "susan",
        "food": "licorice" 
    }
]
```

or susan would have "foods": [{"food":"licorice"}] something like that.

Comment: Assuming it was sorted by the order it needs to be compacted a recursive function should be able to create the array2json recursing on duplicates. Maybe someone will create one for you with a bounty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using json_encode:

```
$persons = array ();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if (empty($persons[$row['person']]))
        $persons[$row['person']] = array ();
    array_push ($persons[$row['person']], $row['food']);
}

echo json_encode ($persons);
```

It should result in the following:

```
{
    'john': [
        'chocolate',
        'pizza',
        'coffee'
    ],
    'susan': [
        'licorice'
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks K Prime. Looks like this is probably the way to do it. Not a HUGE improvement over what I've got, but definitely an improvement. More concise and easier to understand. But I thought that maybe there was a better way.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a kludge, but one way to do what your looking for a little faster using mysql's help is to use this query:

```
SELECT person, GROUP_CONCAT(food) AS foods FROM table GROUP BY person
```

and then you have one string for the foods which you can split into an array

```
$persons = [];
while($person = mysql_fetch_assoc(foodArray)){
    $person['foods'] = explode(", ", $person['foods']);
    array_push($persons, $person);
}
$jsonOut = json_encode($persons);
```

Much simpler, even if it is a bit of a hack.  Also, I also would recommend using json_encode over rolling your own json.  My php is rusty so I'm not certain this code is 100% correct but it's in the ball park.

Comment: thanks Rob, you are correct with using GROUP_CONCAT in this example. For very simple users, I think the GROUP_CONCAT will work well. As things get deeper and the queries get larger I'm not so sure. But you get a point for thinking outside the box.

Comment: I agree, this is not a good solution for complicated queries.  For one, the splitting is very naive, so you better not have a comma in your values.  Also, group_concat has upper limits on length which come into question for larger sets of values.

Answer (score 0):

Not the perfect answer, but

```
$array = array();
while($gotArray=mysql_fetch_assoc(foodArray)){
 $array[] = $gotArray;
};
$jsonOut = array2json($array);
```

Now array2json doesn't exist though there are several versions others have coded. You could just use json_encode($array); which would be close but not correct.

Comment: I gave that a try, but I end up with the duplicate values in the output. So I don't end up with Person:john, foods {food:chocolate, food:pizza.... I get {Person:john, food:chocolate}, {Person: john, food: pizza}, ...

Answer (score 0):

How about using the built in php function [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode)?

You can also use Zend_Json from Zend Framework that will automatically use the native php json function if available, and if not, it's own implementation.

Comment: json_encode will encode each returned array as json. Unless I'm using it wrong, it doesn't group similar properties as I've put in the output I'm looking for.