# How to select distinct hierarchy nodes(MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am using the adjacency model list, and for example:

parent jack id 1

children some_name parent_id 1

children some_name parent_id 1

children some_name parent_id 1

so when i make a query lets say the depth is about 1 lvl, it render this:

jack -> some_name

jack -> some_name

jack -> some_name

but how can i make it render like this:

jack -> {

some_name

some_name

some_name

}

is that possible?, because the keywords DISTINCT and GROUP BY doesn't help :(

Comment: i want it to render like this in MySQL, not in the client PHP

Comment: the GROUP BY operator return one jack, but it also return only one children that is not what i want, i just want to render one parent and many children, and if those children have another childrens, also rendering one parent and many children......

Comment: Or maybe if that is not possible, can you give me an example or how to make it in php, lets say using codeigniter, to render like this?

Comment: as far as i know you cannot achieve this in mysql you have to use php for this structure

Comment: please a little example how can i render it in php? to show in html, i am asking because i will have 24 levels of depth, and i don't want to write much code, do you have some idea on how to make it good?(elegant)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using JSON to format your data.

Using json_encode:

```
$persons = array ();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if (empty($persons[$row['person']]))
        $persons[$row['person']] = array ();
    array_push ($persons[$row['person']], $row['child']);
}

echo json_encode ($persons);
```

It should result in the following:

```
{
    'jack': [
        'some_name',
        'some_name',
        'some_name'
    ]
}
```

Got most of the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951130/443219